# chain a series of SSH logins and process killing

Tags: ssh

I need to log onto 100 pc's and stop the processes ran by a certain user on them. Manually I would say

```
ssh comp01 
killall -u user
```

Which also logs me out of the computer, so then I can run.

```
ssh comp02 
killall -u user
```

etc

is there a way to automate this for comp01-99?

Edit: I've tried `ssh comp01 & killall -u user` but that also kills the main ssh session that I am in to access comp01-99

Comment: Your 'edit' is running `killall` on the local machine. Try like this: `ssh comp1 killall -u user` Also, you might want to consider using `ansible` or similar for these kind of tasks.

Comment: What would be the proper way to do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
for i in {01..99}; do ssh comp$i killall -u user; done
```